# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error attempting to find an object recursively using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to update an item inside my object graph which could span 'n' level in depth.

The following is my object model:

```
   public class Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category : Entity
    {        
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }      
    }

    public class Product : Entity
    {        
    }
```

My view is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Category> Categories`. What I want to do is given a category name, I need to retrieve the first object which matches that from the collection.

For ex, given a list like this and a category Facial Tissue, I need to retrieve the Facial Tissue category object from the collection.

```
Category - Pharmacy
  |-Product - Aspirin
  |-Product - Tylenol
  |-Category - Tooth Paste
  |  |-Product - Crest
  |  |-Product - Colgate
  |-Category - Paper Products
   |-Category - Toilet Paper
   |  |-Product - NoName
   |  |-Product - Charmin
   |-Category - Facial Tissue
      |-Product - Kleenex
Category - Household
  |-Product - Pinesol Cleaner
  |-Product - Garbage Bags
```

I have tried this, but it throws an ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object*** exception when I search level >2 in the hierarchy.

```
 return Categories.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == name) ??
                   Categories.SelectMany(node => node.Categories).Where(lx => lx.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
```

**NOTE:** At times the categories could be null deep down the hierarchy.i.e if there are no categories, then the collection is set to null.Also the solution necessarily need not be using LINQ.

Comment: Which flavour of Linq? Are these queries against a DB?

Comment: I'm using .NET framework 3.5 and this does not run against a DB.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure the lists inside of Category are being instantiated?

Comment: That is not a recursive query, you inspect just one level down...

Comment: Some of the categories could be null deep down the hierarchy.

Comment: Your class definitions don't match your heirarchy you show.  Category has a list of Categories but it looks like it should entities as you have both categories and products under a category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of the following methods to traverse the tree structure recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    var queue = new Queue<T>(source);
    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var item = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return item;
        foreach (var child in childSelector(item))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    return Traverse(new[] { root }, childSelector);
}
```

There is an overload for a single root item, and another that takes a sequence of items.

You could implement them using actual recursion if you prefer, but I prefer an explicit data structure.  If you would like a depth first search instead of a breath first search just change the `Queue` to a `Stack` and update the methods accordingly.

To use it you can do something like this:

```
Category root = new Category();
var searchResult = Traverse(root, item => item.Categories)
            .Where(category => category.Name == "testValue")
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

It also appears that you're getting null errors because you have `Categories` that are null.  If at all possible, I would *highly* encourage you to fix that problem, rather than dealing with it.  If an Entity has no Categories it should have an *empty* list, not a null list.  Having said that, you can adjust the `Traverse` calls as follows if you have any null items:

```
Traverse(root, item => item.Categories ?? Enumerable.Empty<Category>())
```

Comment: Near enough to my stock answer that I won't bother posting it :)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ by itself does not have a dedicated operator for a [*depth-first search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (which is what you need in this case). However, given your requirements, there is a fairly easy solution using a simple recursive function:

```
// Returns the first category with the given name or null, if none is found
Category findCategory(Category start, String name) {
    if (start.name == name) {
        return start;
    }
    if (start.Categories == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (from c in start.Categories
            let found = findCategory(c, name)
            where found != null
            select found).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

You might consider setting the `Categories` property of categories with no subcategories to an empty list instead of `null`. This allows you skip the null check here (and probably also in a lot of other places).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution although it doesn't only use Linq:

```
public Category GetCategory(string name, List<Category> Categories) 
{
    Category found = Categories.FirstOrDefault(cat => cat.Name == name);
    return found ?? Categories.Select(cat => GetCategory(name,cat.Categories))
                              .FirstOrDefault(cat => cat != null);
}
```